# iMovie to Instagram

Tags: conversion, imovie

I have an issue with this process to edit a video (6sec, 10MB => in the instagram range) and share it on Instagram :

- edit in iMovie
- file / share /file
- Resolution 720P, Quality High
- upload on Google Drive
- go to the android app, select new port / other / google drive. I see the video but I'm not able to select it. It's greyd out.

I tried also to convert it with handbrake but same result...